# Spring boot - how to implement cancelling file download?

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a RESTful web service using spring boot to upload and download files. Now I have another requirement. When a large file is getting uploaded or downloaded, user can send a request to cancel the uploading or downloading. How can I implement this feature?